# Representing search failure with a non-nullable type

Tags: c#, non-nullable

I have a method that searches a list of objects based on some of the fields of the object. If a matching object is found, I return it, but I want to be able to represent a no-match situation. Normally I'd return null but I'm working with a non-nullable class I cannot change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options. Use a `Nullable<T>`, or return a bool and use an `out` parameter to get the actual result, e.g.:

```
MyType? FindObject() { }
```

Or:

```
bool FindObject(out MyType result) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation can be handled by [Null Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

What confuse me is that you wrote that you return list of objects and then object. Could you give some details ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you throw an exception? NoObjectFoundException

Comment: This is not a good idea. Exceptions have quite a heavy performance impact and should not be be thrown as part of normal program flow (they are for exceptional situations only).